# Spring adding extra keys when returning java obect in API response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, jackson, objectmapper

I am facing an issue where Spring adds extra keys to my response object. I have attached the response below (Response-2).

I also tried removing @JsonProperty but that also doesnt work because all keys are lowercase.

WANTED RESULT: I want that all my keys should be uppercase as I have declared them in POJO class. I will be sending the JSON via Kafka.

WITHOUT @JsonProperty:

```
{
    "watchlsttype": null,
    "acctno": null,
    "chg_TYPE": null,
    "status": null,
    "rec_TYPE": null,
    "lstchgtimestamp": null,
    "expirytimestamp": null
}
```

API:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/dummyAPI")
    public Object dummyAPI() throws Exception {
        return new InteracAccountAllowList();
    }
```

RESPONSE -2:

```
{
    "ACCTNO": null,
    "EXPIRYTIMESTAMP": null,
    "LSTCHGTIMESTAMP": null,
    "WATCHLSTTYPE": null,
    "STATUS": null,
    "CHG_TYPE": null,
    "REC_TYPE": null,
    "lstchgtimestamp": null,
    "expirytimestamp": null,
    "status": null,
    "rec_TYPE": null,
    "watchlsttype": null,
    "chg_TYPE": null,
    "acctno": null
}
```

CLASS:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    
    public class InteracAccountAllowList {
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String ACCTNO;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String EXPIRYTIMESTAMP;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String LSTCHGTIMESTAMP;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String WATCHLSTTYPE;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String STATUS;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String CHG_TYPE;
    
        @JsonProperty
        private String REC_TYPE;
    
        public String getACCTNO() {
            return ACCTNO;
        }
    
        public void setACCTNO(String aCCTNO) {
            ACCTNO = aCCTNO;
        }
    
        public String getEXPIRYTIMESTAMP() {
            return EXPIRYTIMESTAMP;
        }
    
        public void setEXPIRYTIMESTAMP(String eXPIRYTIMESTAMP) {
            EXPIRYTIMESTAMP = eXPIRYTIMESTAMP;
        }
    
        public String getLSTCHGTIMESTAMP() {
            return LSTCHGTIMESTAMP;
        }
    
        public void setLSTCHGTIMESTAMP(String lSTCHGTIMESTAMP) {
            LSTCHGTIMESTAMP = lSTCHGTIMESTAMP;
        }
    
        public String getWATCHLSTTYPE() {
            return WATCHLSTTYPE;
        }
    
        public void setWATCHLSTTYPE(String wATCHLSTTYPE) {
            WATCHLSTTYPE = wATCHLSTTYPE;
        }
    
        public String getSTATUS() {
            return STATUS;
        }
    
        public void setSTATUS(String sTATUS) {
            STATUS = sTATUS;
        }
    
        public String getCHG_TYPE() {
            return CHG_TYPE;
        }
    
        public void setCHG_TYPE(String cHG_TYPE) {
            CHG_TYPE = cHG_TYPE;
        }
    
        public String getREC_TYPE() {
            return REC_TYPE;
        }
    
        public void setREC_TYPE(String rEC_TYPE) {
            REC_TYPE = rEC_TYPE;
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is pretty simple: Use @JsonProperty("FIELD_NAME") on setter methods.